# Unwanted subsequent pop-up when running/debugging in CLion

Tags: debugging, ide, clion

When I want to debug or just run my code from within CLion using the arrow or bug from the menu, next to the configuration selection:

[image]

Then - since a little while - despite the already selected target in the dropdown to the left, I always get the whole list of targets showing as a pop-up and I have to select the desired target again.

[image]

There is a '1' next to the already selected target. But I have to select this target again to run/debug my code. How can I get rid off this?

I have played with the 'code coverage' feature, but I am not using it any more. Maybe I left a setting behind that is causing this issue!? Any help is welcome. Thanks

(As you may see, I have typed in 'con' in the search field not to expose work internals, but it should not make a difference in terms of understand my problem.)